# Why does headless in python selenium with Chromium not work?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, headless

I'm try to run a code on my Raspberry Pi headless. In normal mode it works totally fine, but if I try to make it headless the code "ignores" it.
I tried different ways of headless, with -- or without , it didn't changes anything.
My current code looks so:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument ("-headless")
options.add_argument ("-disable-gpu")
allesFertig = True


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options =  options, executable_path ='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Any ideas to fix it ?

Comment: Try such lines `opt = Options()
opt.headless = True
`

Comment: add your full code and whoch browser

Comment: @YasserKhalil Thanks for the idea, but sadly this doesn't change anything

Comment: webdriver.Chrome(options=options) are you passing it to chromedriver ?

Comment: Why did you use this line twice `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`? The first one is what you have to keep only. And try using two dashes `("--headless")`

Comment: @PDHide i had tried that also, but then I got an error.

Comment: @YasserKhalil shame on me, that was the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument ("headless")
options.add_argument ("disable-gpu")
allesFertig = True


driver = webdriver.Chrome(options =  options, executable_path ='/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

just remove second driver , you are creating chrome instance again without options thats why its opening GUI

Comment: I think this should be `add_argument("--headless") `

Comment: @YasserKhalil both will work headless and --headless

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sign